# Ajax sourced data for datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I need a `datatable` to be populated with data generated from another ajax call (user input). This is my code:

```
function get(){     

        var getDates    = jQuery.noConflict();

        getDates.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/report.php", 
            data: "start="+getDates("#start").val()+"&end="+getDates("#end").val(),
            success: function(msg){
                //alert(msg);
                getDates('.ajax-sourced').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                //This code works:
                getDates('.ajax-sourced').DataTable(                        
                    {"data":[["2019-11-23","Test1"],["2019-11-23","Test2"]]}    
                 );

                //This code does NOT work even though the returned msg is the same as the data above:
                //msg = {"data":[["2019-11-23","Test1"],["2019-11-23","Test2"]]} 
                getDates('.ajax-sourced').DataTable(msg);
});

    }
```

Any idea why the  `getDates('.ajax-sourced').DataTable(msg);` does not work even if the returned `msg` is the same as the custom typed data?

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly the same?  Is `msg` a string?  If you're using `alert(msg)` and it's showing your value, then yes, it's a string (otherwise would alert [Object]object).   Try `getDates('.ajax-sourced').DataTable(JSON.parse(msg));`

Comment: And that is the correct answer! the msg indeed was a string and not an object. Thank you for the help! You can post your comment as an answer if you like.